# What would cause invisible People/Groups and Multiple Lines of Text fields?

Tags: data-view-web-part, custom-form, people-picker

Since upgrading to SharePoint 2010, I've seen several instances where certain fields in DVWPs do not appear. They seem to function just fine - but users think the field is actually missing from the form.

I've seen this with Multiple Lines of Text fields as well as People/Groups fields. I hadn't thought anything of it until one of the "invisible" People/Groups fields started refusing some Javascript auto-population.

We're using the absolute out-of-the-box Master Page.

Thoughts?

[image: Invisible Fields]

Comment: any target audiences? It's possible the groups had trouble migrating over.

Comment: No sir. The controls are all perfectly functional. I can click in the blank area, enter a name, hit ENTER, and everything is fine. The problem is that users cannot see that.

Answer (score 0):

The "cause" is that my multiple lines of text field was set to Enhanced Rich Text. When I switched it to Rich Text, that field and the People/Groups fields suddenly became visible. And it's more than just cosmetic: suddenly, my little bit of Javascript began correctly auto-populating the People/Groups field with Current User.

Well that's just ridiculous.

I'd still be very curious to find out *why* that would behave in such a way.

Comment: Cory, there are tons of instances where this same sort of thing has happened to me. Telerik has a replacement control for Enhanced Rich Text which seems to resolve some of the issues with that field that I have experienced. In the end, though, I have just ended up completely using my own custom HTML/JS/CSS along with ListData.svc/CSOM and completely removing the SP interface from the equation. Not likely a suggestion you want to hear... But with all the errors I've encountered this has turned out to be faster for me at least.

Comment: Here is the link for the RadEditor, I am in no way associated with Telerik, Just a user: http://sharepoint.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/Pages/default.aspx

Comment: Thanks - I'm in a no-customization environment. I did find a second, equally weird, workaround: add a random multi-line text with rich text field to list, add that to the form, apply class ms-hidden, and all is well. This resolved another mystery issue involving non-commitment with a text field populated via query string.